# List of javac or Diagnostic.java compile time error codes not messages

Tags: java

I want to get all compile-time error codes NOT messages.
For example:

CODE: compiler.err.var.might.not.have.been.initialized (what i want)

MSG: variable x might not have been initialized

can I get that? I googled a lot.
Thx.

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/resources/compiler.properties was pretty easy to find given the property. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take all the output and run a regex to get only codes.
As javac doesn't have a configuration option or feature to print only error codes.